# External call with Vyper

Tags: vyper

I want to call another contract from my vyper contract.

I have read several tutorials and documentations and there is 2 ways to do that:

First method:

```
interface MyExternalContract:
   def public_function1_of_my_external_contract(arg1: int128, arg2: int128)
   def public_function2_of_my_external_contract(arg1: int128, arg2: int128)
   ...

@external
def fonction_of_my_contract():
  MyExternalContract(address). public_function1_of_my_external_contract(1,2)
```

Second method:

```
contract MyExternalContract:
   def public_function1_of_my_external_contract(arg1: int128, arg2: int128)
   def public_function2_of_my_external_contract(arg1: int128, arg2: int128)
   ...

@external
def fonction_of_my_contract():
  MyExternalContract(address). public_function1_of_my_external_contract(1,2)
```

As you can see, the "interface" has been replaced by "contract".

What is the difference between those 2 methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `contract` is deprecated in v0.2.1, and replaced with `interface` keyword.

More detail at [VIP: Change contract keyword to interface #1825](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/issues/1825)

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Are you able to add a quick reference to it?